# ASCII Message in TV show?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis

So I was watching a popular series tonight (Person Of Interest) when suddenly during a frame change I noticed a very quick blue screen with writing.

At the time I never thought anything of it as it was to quick, it was embedded within a one second interval gap at 20:50 to 20:51.

I tried using my media player to pause on the frame but media players can only pause on the second not between. So I fired up after effects and zoomed into the frames during this time period and this is what I found:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that it is in an obscure code known as "ASCII" (with an occasional nonstandard hex digit); the first line would translate as:

Terrorism refers to the use of threat of force of violence